# Predicting with a previously saved model: (0) Invalid argument: indices[0,9] = 14914 is not in [0, 14480)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, text-classification

I'm trying to use a saved to predict unseen text data. But I get this error about the embedding lookup.
I'm not sure how to fix it. Similar errors had to do with the vocab size. However, since I'm not training a model, my case is different.
This is the code snippet

```
processed_train_sequences = pad_sequences(processed_train_sequences, maxlen=38, padding='post')
print("processed train sequence",processed_train_sequences)
saved_model = load_model('TrainModel9.h5', compile = True)

pred_prob = saved_model.predict(processed_train_sequences)
print(pred_prob)
```

This is the full traceback.

```
  File "PSOforDA_withoutparallelprocessing.py", line 212, in <module>
    cost, pos = optimizer.optimize(f, iters=1)  # returns a tuple of the local best cost and the local best position among the swarm.
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyswarms/discrete/binary.py", line 176, in optimize
    self.swarm.current_cost = compute_objective_function(
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyswarms/backend/operators.py", line 239, in compute_objective_function
    return objective_func(swarm.position, **kwargs)
  File "PSOforDA_withoutparallelprocessing.py", line 127, in f
    j =  [f_per_particle(x[i], alpha,sent) for i in range(n_particles)]
  File "PSOforDA_withoutparallelprocessing.py", line 127, in <listcomp>
    j =  [f_per_particle(x[i], alpha,sent) for i in range(n_particles)]
  File "PSOforDA_withoutparallelprocessing.py", line 104, in f_per_particle
    pred_prob = saved_model.predict(processed_train_sequences)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 88, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 650, in _call
    return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1661, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1745, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 593, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[0,9] = 14914 is not in [0, 14480)
         [[node sequential_9/embedding_9/embedding_lookup (defined at PSOforDA_withoutparallelprocessing.py:104) ]]
         [[sequential_9/embedding_9/embedding_lookup/_6]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[0,9] = 14914 is not in [0, 14480)
         [[node sequential_9/embedding_9/embedding_lookup (defined at PSOforDA_withoutparallelprocessing.py:104) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_predict_function_2294]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_9/embedding_9/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_9/embedding_9/embedding_lookup/1381 (defined at /usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py:113)

Input Source operations connected to node sequential_9/embedding_9/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_9/embedding_9/embedding_lookup/1381 (defined at /usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py:113)

Function call stack:
predict_function -> predict_function
```

After running some test, i think this error shows up when one of the words you are trying to predict is not in the embedding?
How do i assign zero to those?
or how do i catch the error using a try-except block?

Answer (score 1):

So I had trained the original model with `vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1`  which meant it had a reduced vocabulary compared with the embedding. So I retrained it with `vocab = 3000000 + 1`. Thus giving it access to more words. The embedding I'm using is word2vec. This solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer, I'm having the same issue. If I use a number different than the weights matrix I run into an issue. How did you solve this?